# Unity c# destroy spawned prefab with mouse click

Tags: collision-detection, unity-game-engine

I have a script to spawn cats at random positions in the game and when the user clicks on them they should be destroyed. I am having trouble with my script however and was wondering if anyone knew what was wrong with the raycast?

```
public void CatClick () {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
                Ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

                if (Physics.Raycast(Ray, out RaycastHit)) {

                    Destroy(RaycastHit.collider.gameObject);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Another way** to do it:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class CatDestructor : MonoBehaviour 
 {


     // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {

    }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () 
    {

    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        // Destroy game object
        Destroy (this.gameObject);
    }
 }
```

Put this script on "cat" prefab and if you click on it, it will destroy the "cat".

**Or** *you must* put your code to update function like this:

```
 void Update(){
   if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){ // if left button pressed...
     Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
     RaycastHit hit;
     if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)){
       // the object identified by hit.transform was clicked
       // do whatever you want
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be checking in the update function?

Answer (score 1):

like Arne said, make sure you check it in the update function, also if it's a 2d collider make sure you change it to

```
 if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
 {
      Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
      RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.GetRayIntersection(ray, Mathf.Infinity);

       if (hit.collider != null)
       {
                // do whatever you want to do here
       }
 }
```